# Using Gensim shows "Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec being used"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim

I am trying to run a program using the Gensim library of the Python with the version 3.6.
Whenever I ran the program, I came across these statements:

```
C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gensim-2.0.0-py3.6-win32.egg\gensim\utils.py:860: UserWarning: detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial
  warnings.warn("detected Windows; aliasing chunkize to chunkize_serial")
Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used
```

I do not understand what is the meaning behind `Slow version of gensim.models.doc2vec is being used`. How the gensim is selecting the slow version and if I want the fastest version then what I need to do?

Comment: How did you install gensim?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I used pip only for installation.

Comment: So, looking at the errors you are encountering it's likely due to all the typical issues that arise when trying to install the scipy stack on Windows, particularly `numpy`. My advice? Just go with anaconda. It was made to deal with this very issue. Or switch to a *nix environment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga its great advice... thanks man.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Highlighting @juanpa.arrivillaga's comment, as it helped me resolve this issue.
If you installed anaconda :

- uninstall gensim : `pip uninstall gensim`
- install it with the anaconda package manager : `conda install gensim`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is to do with the some underlying packages not being up to date. Gordon's post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/TaAn5_6sb0Y) helped me.

But in short:

1. Uninstall Gensim

   sudo pip3 uninstall gensim
2. Install python3-dev build-essential

   sudo apt-get install python3-dev build-essential
3. Re-Install Gensim

   sudo pip3 install --upgrade gensim

Notes:

- Instructions above are for systems where pip and apt-get are used to
  manage packages
- pip3 is the python3 version of pip

Comment: ok I am trying to upgrade it. I am using windows. Still familiar with the above commands. Hence, will manage

Comment: Got these errors after applying your method: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/1172c06a0176920d04e1a424af1fac55

Comment: Sorry yeah not sure how you would solve it on Windows systems. I have just switched to my Windows env myself but have not had not issues (I did a pip3 install gensim)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem (I'm running ubuntu). I found out that if i'm using directly the version from github, the problem is fixed.

So there are 2 solutions: (first uninstall gensim using `pip uninstall gensim`)

1. download and unzip the gensim zip file from gensim's [github page](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim), then CD to the folder of the zip content and run the command `python setup.py install`
2. run this command `pip install git+https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim@master#egg=gensim`

I used the second and now I don't get the warnings